# WPF - Get relative Canvas coordinates after a drag/drop operation?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

In WPF, I have a custom "toolbox" which consists of Label controls and some vector icons docked to the left of the screen.

In the center, I have a Canvas control which I eventually am going to need to serialize out the relative coordinates (for other platforms) for this "designer surface".

Basic question, I can drag/drop controls from this psuedo-control box onto a Canvas but I need to know how to place this WPF control properly in the canvas, under where the mouse pointer is, *realtive* to the Canvas and not the screen or main Window.

What are the functions that needed to be called so that I can ensure that if I drop a Button control at 10%, 20% of the canvas, I get an actual location back and the button drops where expected?

Comment: Don't you have the relative position in the dropped event? If not, doesn't substracting the Canvas' position give you the relative position to the Canvas?

Comment: DragEventArgs.GetPosiiton(): `e.GetPosition(whateverCanvasControl)`. Relative/proportional coordinates are relatively easy arithmetic.

Comment: My "e.source" the drag/drop is the Canvas element, not the item being dropped.  What properties am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events provide a `Point` structure. 
Converting of positions can be done by `Control.PointToScreen` and `TargetControl.PointToClient`.